# How to fix Syntax Error when Bulk Inserting to MS SQL through pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, bulkinsert

Tying to insert a pipe delimitated csv file to an empty Microsoft SQL database table with the following code:

```
 import pyodbc


class c_bulk_insert:
    def __init__(self, csv_file_nm, sql_server_nm, db_nm, db_table_nm):
        # Connect to the database, perform the insert, and update the log table.
        conn = self.connect_db(sql_server_nm, db_nm)
        self.insert_data(conn, csv_file_nm, db_table_nm)
        conn.close

    def connect_db(self, sql_server_nm, db_nm):
        # Connect to the server and database with Windows authentication.
        conn_string = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=' + sql_server_nm + ';DATABASE=' + db_nm + ';Trusted_Connection=yes;'
        conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_string, autocommit=True)

        return conn

    def insert_data(self, conn, csv_file_nm, db_table_nm):
        # Insert the data from the CSV file into the database table.
        # Assemble the BULK INSERT query. Be sure to skip the header row by specifying FIRSTROW = 2.
        qry = "BULK INSERT  " + db_table_nm + "  FROM '" + csv_file_nm + "' WITH ( FORMAT = 'CSV', FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = '|' )"
        #"'[ WITH ( [[|] FORMAT = 'CSV'],  [[|] FIRSTROW = 2])]"
        
        

        # Execute the query
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        success = cursor.execute(qry)
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close

bulk_insert = c_bulk_insert(r"C:filepath/filename.csv", 'servername', 'databasename', 'tablename')
```

I keep getting an error of "Incorrect syntax near 'FORMAT'. (102)"
Based on what i am seeing, the syntax looks correct; but if anyone sees something I might be missing, please let me know
Happy to answer any questions

Comment: Are you sure the FIELDTERMINATOR is correct '|' ?  
It's not ',' by chance ?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#format--csv), the `FORMAT` parameter is only available in (currently) *fully supported* versions of SQL Server.

Comment: Yes, purposely went with the | to avoid potential issues